# How does EmailProperty differ from StringProperty?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

How does `EmailProperty` differ from `StringProperty`?  Consider these two examples:

```
# example 1: store an e-mail address in an EmailProperty
class MyModel(db.Model):
  email_address = db.EmailProperty()
m = MyModel()
m.email_address = db.Email("larry@example.com")

# example 2: store an e-mail address in a StringProperty
class MyModel(db.Model):
  email_address = db.StringProperty()
m = MyModel()
m.email_address = "larry@example.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `entity.to_xml()`, an EmailProperty will come back as [gd:email](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/1.0/elements.html#gdEmail) in your entity's Atom representation.

Note that using an EmailProperty **does not** provide automatic validation of email address formatting.

Comment: gd:email is part of the GData API, which is fully compliant with AtomPub.

Comment: so it is not useful for normal atom.