# What is the meaning of EmailProperty, PhoneNumberProperty etc... gae-datastore properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does EmailProperty differ from StringProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268390/how-does-emailproperty-differ-from-stringproperty)

In EmailProperty [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#EmailProperty):

> Neither the property class nor the
>   value class perform validation of
>   email addresses, they just store the
>   value.

So why to have it instead of StringProperty

Answer (score 2):

It purely for semantics.

It's handy if you want to write functions that iterate over the `properties` of a Model.

I would guess the idea is to encourage everyone to write nice semantic [custom properties for their models](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/extending_models.html) and leading by example.